# Customize Firefox Developer dev tools color theme

Tags: firefox, browser, themes, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

Just as title says, I'd like to know if it's possible to change the color theme of Firefox Developer dev tools. Light and dark theme are nice, but I'd like to use a code color theme like Monokai or something similar, how can I do that?

Below you can see the current dark theme in the dev tools:

[[image: firefox dark theme screenshot [1]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the [answer to this in the Mozilla support forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1097887) and basically you have to modify the css style creating an overriding chrome stylesheet.

> You would have to write your own style rules and apply them via
>   userChrome.css or Stylish. Use the !important flag to override
>   existing style rules.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception
>
> The customization files userChrome.css (user interface) and
>   userContent.css (websites) are located in the chrome folder in the
>   Firefox profile folder.
>
> http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_configuration

Answer (score 3):

It's not documented (yet), but you could make an [Add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons) that uses [`gDevTools.registerTheme(themeDefinition)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/DevToolsAPI#Methods) to create your own dev tools theme.

Comment: Thank you for your time but actually I found the [answer on the Mozilla support forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1097887) some days ago, but I totally forgot to close the answer here on SO.